# how to use query with parameters in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use a query method in Angular JS service connecting to a restful web service with the url `/users/userId/sensors/`. The restful web service works fine when I enter the url in the browser but when I want to get the result in Angular service when calling the find method I get nothing.

**controller.js**:

```
appControllers.controller('sensorController',
    function ($scope, Scopes, SensorService) {
        var userId = Scopes.get('id');
        $scope.sensors = [];
        $scope.sensors = function () {
        SensorService.find(userId, function (data) {
            $scope.sensors = data;
        });
    };
});
```

**service.js**:

```
appServices.factory('SensorService', function ($resource) {
    var url = '/iots-web/rest/users/:userId/sensors/:path';
    return $resource(url, {path: '@path', userId: '@userId'}, {
        query: {method: 'GET',isArray: true},
        find: {method: 'GET', params: {userId: '@userId'}, isArray: true},
        create: {method: 'POST'},
        update: {method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'}},
        delete: {method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'}}
    });
});
```

Scopes is another service I use to share the usrId between controllers and it works fine so there is no problem with getting the userId.

Comment: Have you tried fiddler to check what call you are making to the  web service  http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: thanks Isaac i did check it's an awsome tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way to pass `userId` into resource call would be:

```
SensorService.find({userId: userId}, function(data) {
    $scope.sensors = data;
});
```

Also to avoid confusion, it's better to rename sensors function to something else:

```
$scope.sensors = [];
$scope.getSensors = function() {
    SensorService.find({userId: userId}, function(data) {
        $scope.sensors = data;
    });
};
```

Comment: This is probably the issue, yes. `$resource` methods expect to receive an object holding the parameters.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the issue. I tried passing userId as an object and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem looks as you are trying to access a javascript variable in an anonymous function

```
    $scope.sensors = function () {

    SensorService.find(userId, function (data) {
        $scope.sensors = data;
    });
```

userId does not exist in this anonymous function.

Comment: Actually, `userId` is defined three lines above (though we can't say what `Scopes.get('id')` actually returns)

Comment: it is defined but it is never passed into the anonymous function. You have touched. that is the solution though

Comment: It doesn't need to be passed, it is visible there - http://plnkr.co/edit/ypJLr3KMsr4KaHONApo7?p=preview

Though, I agree it is not the best practice and _should_ be passed in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.sensors = [];

$scope.sensors = function () {
    SensorService.find(userId, function (data) {
        $scope.sensors = data;
    });
};
```

This seems suspicious to me. You first assign an empty Array to `$scope.sensors`, then override this value with a function, and then override it again with `data`, when it arrives.

Try fixing this first and then check if your problem still persists.